# Длина соли и длина выходной стройки алгоритма blowfish

Tags: blowfish, php, криптография, шифрование

Здравствуйте. В [мануале php](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.crypt.php) сказано, что Blowfish-шифрование использует соль след. формата: "$2a$", весовой параметр из двух цифр, "$" и 22 цифры из алфавита "./0-9A-Za-z" . Но на деле вместо 22 у меня почему-то используется только 21 символ.

```
$var = "1111111111111111111112";//22-й символ помечен двойкой

echo strlen($var);//выводит 22

echo crypt("12345", "$2a$11$".$var);// выводит $2a$11$111111111111111111111uDWduZDJM79lPV0duPxKCR2XEmS5ly2q
```

Как видно 22-й символ обрезался и не попал в соль.

Вопрос1: Как объяснить выше описанное поведение?

Вопрос2: У меня на php длина выходной строки (хэша с солью) всегда равна 60 байт (ну или 60 символов латинского алфавита). Это общий стандарт? стандарт php? Если да, то где описан?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Соль задается из алфавита "./0-9A-Za-z" (64 символа), т.е. каждый символ представляет из себя 6 бит. Это напоминает кодировку [BASE64](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
Вы задаете 22 символа это 22*6 = 132 бита. Для Blowfish соль используется 128 бит из-за этого последние 4 бита не используется. Когда выводится результат, то 128 бит также дополняются 4 нулевыми битами, т.е. от последнего символа остается только 2 старших бита.
В вашем примере: 2 (111000) -> u(110000), т.е. последний символ Вы можете задавать любой с точность до 2-х старших битов и это не будет влиять на хэш.